# Floating point division returns integer numbers

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the average of two floating point numbers, but whatever the input, I am getting an integer returned.

What should I do to make this work?

```
public class Program
{
    public static float Average(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b) / 2;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Average(2, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: "but that is obviously not it" - what is the error message or problem you are seeing?

Comment: I will add the output description, since it might not be clear enough

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There're *two* problems with your code

1. Evident one - *Integer division* - e.g. `1 / 2 == 0` not `0.5` since result must be integer
2. Hidden one - *Integer overflow* - e.g. `a + b` can overflow `int.MaxValue` and you'll get *negative* result

The most accurate implementation is

```
public static float Average(int a, int b)
{
    return 0.5f * a + 0.5f * b;
}
```

Tests:

```
Average(1, 2);                       // 1.5
Average(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue); // some large positive value
```

Comment: I would personally find `((float)a + (float)b) / 2.0` to be more readable, and more obviously similar to the original code. Let the compiler optimize the division by 2 into a multiplication by 0.5 if that is really an improvement. (In this case, it may even be a premature pessimization.)

Comment: @Cody Gray: there're many possible implementations of the idea; the only thing is that `2.0` means `double`, not `float`; so your version should be `((float)a + (float)b) / 2.0f;` (please, notice `f` suffix)

Answer (score 9):

The trick is to write the expression as `0.5 * a + 0.5 * b`, which *also* obviates the potential for `int` overflow (acknowledge Dmitry Bychenko).

Currently your expression is evaluated in *integer arithmetic*, which means that any fractional part is discarded.

In setting one of the values in each term to a floating point literal, the *entire* expression is evaluated in floating point.

Finally, if you want the type of the expression to be a `float`, then use

```
0.5f * a + 0.5f * b
```

The `f` suffix is used to denote a `float` literal.

Comment: ...or `(a + b) / 2.0`

Comment: There are a few alternatives but I like to see the "thing that does the converting" as the first thing in the expression.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I would like to add that I had to change the type to double, since I was getting the: Error(s):
(15:16) Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Leff: I've put something at the end.

Comment: Thank you again for your nice explanation! I will accept your answer as soon as I am able to.

Comment: Although I personally think that @DmitryBychenko's answer is better; do feel free to reconsider.

Answer (score 2):

`return (a + b) / 2F;` tells the compiler to treat the number as a float, otherwise it will be treated as an `int`.

Comment: I changed it, judging it to be a typo on the part of the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
public static float Average(int a, int b)
{
    return (float)(a + b) / 2;
}
```

Comment: It is returning 2.5 for Average(2,3). Please check.@MikhailNeofitov

Comment: i'm sorry. Sure it is correct, as only numerator is casting to float

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(float)(a + b) / 2.0
```

This will return float

Sorry, if anyone has answered the same way (I did not read all answers)